# Creating custom node operation to execute via JBoss CLI

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-cli

We'd like to perform occasional configuration refreshes on some of our servers, but we'd prefer that that operation wasn't exposed via a web-service, but rather that the infrastructure guys could call a command via the JBoss CLI to do a refresh.

Is it possible to create new commands / node operations that are exposed via the CLI? Googling seems to show only various methods of accessing the existing operations, and [this page](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/CLIExtensibilityForLayeredProducts), which is a bit light on details of how it's called.

Comment: Do you mean creating CLI commands or operations? If so that can only be done if you extend WildFly. However you can create CLI scripts.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of custom CLI commands, just to kick off an admin operation from the command-line instead of going the web-service / auth route. I'm beginning to suspect that CLI doesn't support that kind of thing though.

Comment: The only way that would be possible is with extending CLI or creating an extension in WildFly itself.

Comment: Is there any support for that? Or are we talking grabbing source and recompiling?

Comment: There is some [documentation](http://docs.wildfly.org/13/Extending_WildFly.html) on it, but it's really more about adding extensions to WildFly. It's possible it would be better to dynamically generate scripts or something similar.

Comment: I pretty much just need to call a method on a `@Singleton` within a deployment in the system - would that be possible?

Comment: In some cases that should work. It depends if you're changing resources that your deployment is using.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see, thanks.